# Google Golang SDK Use Custom CA Bundle

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to pull messages from a Google Cloud Pub/Sub Subscription using the Google Cloud Client Library for Go (https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/pubsub).

I am going through an HTTP proxy that uses TLS interception, so I need the pubsub client (it appears to be using gRPC) to use a custom CA cert bundle for its request verification. How can I make this work? Also, is there a way to configure proxy support other than setting http_proxy and https_proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else interested in the answer to this problem, you can set an environmental variable:

```
export GRPC_DEFAULT_SSL_ROOTS_FILE_PATH=/path/to/my/cert/bundle.pem
```

Also, you can display more debug information by setting this environmental variable:

```
export GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG
```

For the list of all env vars you can set see here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md